# How to Insert Records into UWP Community Toolkit DataGrid?

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

I'm using the UWP Community Toolkit's DataGrid to present information from my ActivityLogEntryModel as follows:

```
 <controls:DataGrid x:Name="ActivityLogDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityLogEntries}" 
                           GridLinesVisibility="All"
                           HeadersVisibility="Column"
                           AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Entry Date" Binding="{Binding EntryDate}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Message}"/>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>

        </controls:DataGrid>
        <Button Command="{Binding CreateActivityLogEntryAsync}">
            <TextBlock Text="Add Entry"></TextBlock>
        </Button>
```

ViewModel Observable Collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<ActivityLogEntryModel> ActivityLogEntries { get; private set; }
private  MainViewModel()
    {

        timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)
        };
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += TimeOnTick;

        PlayCommand = new DelegateCommand(Play);
        StopCommand = new DelegateCommand(Stop);
        RecordCommand = new DelegateCommand(Record);
        PauseCommand = new DelegateCommand(Pause);
        OutputDevices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation>();
        RecordingDevices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation>();
        ActivityLogEntries = new ObservableCollection<ActivityLogEntryModel>();

        Volume = 100;
        PlaybackSpeed = 100;
        recordingFormat = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
        recordingFormat.Audio = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(16000,1,16);  
        EnableCommands(false);
        player = new MediaPlayerElement();
    }
```

I've added a Button control below the DataGrid that, when clicked, presents a dialog with empty fields from the ActivityLogEntryModel class.  How do I create this dialog and ensure that changes are saved to the model and my DataGrid is refreshed with the new entry?

Comment: Do you mean insert new `DataGridTextColumn`  dynamically?

Comment: Make `ActivityLogEntries` an `ObservableCollection<T>` and add an item of type T to this one to insert it into the `DataGrid`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Not necessarily a new header column, but rather a new row of data.

Comment: If you just add the new row you could add new item  to  `ActivityLogEntries`.